# bootstrap external style sheet not styling html

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles, inline

I don't know why, but for some or odd reason the specific style for a p tag inside does not style when using a custom style sheet css, but works perfectly fine when doing inline.

Obviously I'm trying to avoid using inline, because it's not the best practice.Using Bootstrap

```
<h1 class="page-header">Properties</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-4 main_content">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/home_image2.jpg" />
        <p>CHATHAM<br />
        London, Uk
        </p>
    </div>
```

The html.

The CSS:

```
.main_content p {
font-size:24px;
background:#262626;}
```

Both the font size as well as the background color doesn't seem to work

I have tried targeting it as a ID, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you loading your custom css after the bootstraps css?

Comment: yes i am. but the thing is. The CSS works with al other elements perfectly fine. It's just this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

The solution I came up with was to change the name of the class affecting the div.

Even though did a search to check if I might have been using it somewhere else, and nothing came up, this solution worked out perfectly fine.

This is the name change I used.

```
.main_content_home p {
font-size:20px; 
background:#262626; 
color:#FFF;
padding: 12px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.main_content p {
font-size:24px !important;
background:#262626 !important;}
```

Comment: nope. I have tried !important @amit jain @ Gorostas. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.main_content p {
font-size:24px !important;
background:#262626 !important;
}
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9080/

But it works without !important, i dont think !important is not godd to use, please check you other css maybe you are overriding some more classes, if you can please make a working fiddle or send us a link

Answer (score 0):

Or write with upper class.

```
.page-header .col-lg-4.main_content p {
    font-size:24px;
    background:#262626;
}
```

Comment: no use. It seems to be an issue that targets certain elements in bootstrap.

Comment: ok then. body .page-header .main_content p {
    font-size:24px;
    background:#262626;
}

Comment: Infact write all main classes before .page-header class if there is. like, '.container .inner-container .sample-div .page-header p {'